# change the fluid amount in inflow

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

I want to make the fluid go to the end of u. These are my inflow and domain settings. But the fluid is stooping here. How can I solve it? please help.Thanks in advance.[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Expand scene frame range, and time settings for simulation. Or increase simulation speed, if you want to keep current length of it.

Answer (score 1):

Another issue that you will likely encounter, is that your tube obstacle impinges itself in at least 2 places where there is a sharp bend.
The fluid simulator requires a well defined inside versus outside surface to function properly.
Also, you may need to increase the resolution to get a proper result.

In addition to Serge L's recommendations, you could try reducing the gravity setting under the Scene tab. Also, you don't show your obstacle settings. If the ends of the tube are open, the Volume Initialization should be set to 'Shell' and you may also want to adjust the amount of slip.

Answer (score 0):

**Your fluid is stopping because the simulation reached the end of the frames Blender automatically sets when creating a new file.**

To change the amount of frames in your scene go to the Render Settings tab with the camera icon and under "Dimensions" and change the "End Frame" value to fit your simulation.

[image: Render Dimensions Settings]

**A different approach would be to change the time or speed of your fluid sim.**

To do that go to the settings of your fluid domain and under "Fluid" change the time "End" value to the amount of seconds that fit your scene's amount of frames. Blender's default frame rate is 24fps which means ~10.4 seconds at 250 total frames.
Otherwise, if you're going for a still, you should just change the speed of your fluid sim. This will result in less time and memory needed when baking.

[image: Fluid Domain Settings]